# Circular Dependency Injection in constructors

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

Given this scenario:

```cs
public class A : IA
{
    private IB _ib { get; }
    public A(IB ib)
    {
        _ib = ib;
    }
}

public class B : IB
{
    private IA _ia { get; }
    public B(IA ia)
    {
        _ia = ia;
    }
}
```

And at `Startup.cs` both are registered as `Singleton`.

Why does this doesn't fall into circular dependency?

Comment: To confirm, you're asking why this *isn't* a failing because of a circular dependency? If it's registered like this: `services.AddSingleton<IA, A>(); services.AddSingleton<IB, B>();` and then you resolve `IA`, it is a circular dependency and it does fail. How are you registering them, and what are you resolving?

Comment: @ScottHannen As you say, they are registered like `services.AddSingleton<IA, A>(); services.AddSingleton<IB, B>();`. I'm letting the framework to do the resolving. Actually, today I deployed to a dev environment and does not work, but locally in `Visual Studio` it does. Weird.

Comment: I just did it in a simple unit test. I expected it to fail and it did. If it's registered as in my comment and nothing else is registered, it can only fail. With 100% certainty, if it is not failing, something is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, as indicated in your comments, the dependencies are registered like this:

```
services.AddSingleton<IA, A>();
services.AddSingleton<IB, B>();
```

...resolving either `IA` or `IB` will fail with an exception. This is provable with a unit test.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestCircularDependency()
{
    var services = new ServiceCollection();
    services.AddSingleton<IA, A>();
    services.AddSingleton<IB, B>();
    var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    var a = provider.GetService<IA>();
    var b = provider.GetService<IB>();
}
```

Either resolution fails with an exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: A circular dependency was detected for the service of type 'UnitTestProject1.IB'.

For this *not* to fail is impossible. Things frequently happen in our code that appear to be impossible, but in virtually every case the cause is an assumption that can't be correct.

You've also mentioned that it works in one environment but not in another. The assumption (which I've made lots of times) is that the same code is running in both environments, but in this case it's not.

The only way that `IA` can be resolved in this case is if there is another implementation of `IA` or another implementation of `IB` (or very unlikely - `null` is injected as the dependency into one or the other.)

---

This sort of problem is interesting because when we see something that appears to be impossible, our tendency (mine at least) is often to stare at it wondering how the impossible is happening. Once we've determined that what we *think* is happening is impossible, that's an indication that we should begin questioning every other assumption which has led us to that conclusion. One of them must be false.